# AngularJS unknown provider after code refactoring

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-provider

I have an app which worked great, until I decided to refactor the code and use Gulp for my project. Here is the error I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: _Provider <- _ <- utilsFactory <- storageService <- httpRequestInterceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state
```

Since I'm not sure how to read this error and if they all have an issue or if it's only one of them, here are the two places where I use some of these providers when I start my app:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, storageService, modalsFactory, appFactory, _) { ... }
```

And:

```
angular.module("mediaControl").controller("loginCtrl", function ($state, $translate, authService, utilsFactory, appFactory, storageService) { ... }
```

In my index.html file, I have:

```
<!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="src/mediaControl.js"></script>
  ...
  <script src="src/login/providers/httpRequestInterceptor.service.js"></script>
  ...
  <script src="src/common/providers/utils.factory.js"></script>
  <script src="src/common/providers/storage.service.js"></script>
  ...
  <script src="src/login/login.controller.js"></script>
  ...
  <!-- endinject -->
```

What I checked/did:

- Check if Gulp put all of the necessary js files in index.html and in the good order (seems ok to me)
- Check the names of the providers (I didn't change them during the refactoring though)
- Try to remove my custom providers from loginCtrl and app.run (I still have the same error when I'm doing this)

I read the documentation and some SO questions, but I don't see anything that I would do wrong, considering that my app worked before the refactoring (which consists in reorganizing my file structure, renaming the files, and starting to rewrite the code using ES6 standards). Any idea about what could be wrong here?

Comment: It is missingn the underscore or lodash `_` provider you need to see why the file that defines that service/provider isn't loaded.  Read the error as a chain from right to left things on the right depend on things on the left, ultimately it couldn't get the thing on the left for all the stuff on the right to work.

Comment: @shaunhusain  Thanks for the tip on how to read the provider error. For some error, I didn't notice the "_" at the end of it and thought the error was on utilsFactory... I fixed it, it works like a charm now!

Comment: No problem yeah easy to see that as part of the word Provider _ is a sneaky one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed by @shaunhusain, the lodash provider was missing in my index.html. I fixed my Gulpfile so that the file is injected as well, and it works.